# order products by price

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low,
When I click on the link from the view it doesn't chnage the order of the products.
this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products($category_url, Request $request){
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {
       $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
       $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
   Route::get('shop/{category_url}?sort=DESC','ShopController@products');
   Route::get('shop/{category_url}?sort=ASC','ShopController@products');
```

tihs is the view:

```
   <a href="{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'])}}?sort=DESC" style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
   <a href="{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'])}}?sort=ASC" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the route like

```
Route::get('shop/{category_url}','ShopController@products');
```

Define the default value of sort in your class

```
static $sort= 'asc';
```

Example code to get products with sort

```
class ShopController extends Controller{

    static $sort = 'asc';

public function products($category_url, Request $request){

    // Your Code

        //check the value you are getting
        //echo $request->input('sort');
        $sort = !is_null($request->input('sort')) ? $request->input('sort') : static::$sort;
        $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

  // Your Code
  }


// Your Code
...
}
```

Comment: I wrote what u said:     public function products($category_url, Request $request){
     
        Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
        if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {
       
   echo $request->input('sort');
   $sort = !is_null($request->input('sort')) ? $request->input('sort') : static::$sort;
$products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
  return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort'));

Comment: it's echo the correct value, but still  the ordering doesnt work

Comment: Just check this one is working `Product::orderBy('price', 'DESC')->get();` and `Product::orderBy('price', 'ASC')->get();` for testing. and the route should be only `Route::get('shop/{category_url}','ShopController@products');`

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the $sort value.

Do:

```
dd($sort);
```

Comment: How would this be an answer to the OP? In the current for your "answer" seems to be more suited as a comment than an actual answer.